# IntelliJ IDEA module-info warnings

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I created a modular JavaFX project using Maven within IntelliJ IDEA (2020.3.1). To add some icons to the UI, I included the Fontawesome-, JavaFX- and Core-[Ikonli](https://kordamp.org/ikonli/) libraries through *File > Project-Structure > Dependencies* and added them to the **pom.xml** as well as to **module-info.java**, as follows.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
    <artifactId>ikonli-core</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.0</version>          
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
     <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
     <version>11.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
    <artifactId>ikonli-fontawesome-pack</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```
module my.app {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    requires org.kordamp.iconli.core;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.fontawesome;
    
    ...
}
```

The application runs and builds without any warnings or errors, but IntelliJ's linter is hightlighting the following two warnings for each of the Ikonli dependencies inside **module-info.java**:

> Module 'my.app' reads package 'org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx' from both 'org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx' and 'org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx'

> Ambiguous module reference: 'org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx'

Did I overlook something or is IntelliJ's linter mistaking there?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please file an issue at YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues, providing a sample project to it if possible. Thanks

Comment: I opened [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-269742), including a replication sample project.